# How to understand and explain the sign of variable changes after including its square in a regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, linear

How to understand and explain the sign of variable changes after including its square in a regression? For example, in a regression, X loads negatively, but X loads positively after further including the square of X. Does this means something wrong with the regression specification or not? Do we need to take some measures to address this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Have you graphed the points in a scatterplot?

Comment: Two small comments (answers cover all the main issues already): **1.** if $\beta_2$ is the quadratic ($x^2$ term) population parameter and $\beta_1$ is the linear term ($x$) parameter, then $x^*=-\beta_1/2\beta_2$ is the turning point of the quadratic. **2.** If you want to compare coefficients across different order polynomials, you may find the coefficients easier to interpret for that purpose if you use orthogonal polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely plausible behavior. Consider the situation below.

[image: XY plot]

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N, , 2)
y <- -x^2 + x + rnorm(N, 0, 0.1)
d <- data.frame(
  X = x,
  Y = y
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point()
```

It should come as no surprise that the coefficient on `x` in a simple linear regression is less than zero in order to account for the generally decreasing trend in the data.

```r
L1 <- lm(y ~ x) # Linear term of x only
summary(L1)$coef # I get -1.1271544 as the x-term coefficient
```

However, there is curvature in the data. If we model that with a quadratic term, the sign of the coefficient on the linear `x` variable becomes positive.

```r
L2 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)) # Include quadratic term
summary(L2)$coef # I get a coefficient of 0.94773194 on the linear x term
                 # and a coefficient of -0.99238209 on the quadratic term
                 # to account for the generally decreasing trend
```

None of this means that you did the regression modeling right, but the changing sign upon adding the quadratic term is not the red flag that it might appear to be.

Comment: As an aside, including that quadratic term does not make this a nonlinear model. The linearity refers to the notion from linear algebra of being linear in the parameters, not linear in the data. This is a common mistake that I believe leads people to underestimate linear and generalized models, falsely believing them to be incapable of handling curvature in the data. Thus, I have removed the [tag:nonlinear-regression] tag.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 0):

To complement Dave’s (+1) excellent example, you can think generally about the bias that can emerge if you omit the quadratic term in your model. If your *true* model is quadratic, then you have the form

$$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2 x^2 + \epsilon. $$

If the model you *estimate* is

$$ y = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 x + \nu, $$

the estimates from this reduced model are going to be biased (with respect to the coefficient on the linear term in the main quadratic model): more specifically

$$ \gamma_1 = \beta_1 + \beta_2 \frac{\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(X^2,X)}{\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(X)}, $$
where that covariance-variance ratio simply the regression coefficient of regressing $X^2$ on $X$. Now if the $\beta_1 > 0$, we could nevertheless have $\beta_2 \frac{\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(X^2,X)}{\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(X)}$ be sufficiently negative to make $\gamma_1 < 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations!